# How to iterate QVariant?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I did updated my QTCreator to 5.5 and created a new project, in implementation I didn't get QList values in QML (from signal call):

Class:

```
...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication application(argc, argv);

    const QString mainQmlApp = QStringLiteral("qrc:///Exemplo.qml");
    QQuickView view;

    qmlRegisterType<ExemploController>("org.qtproject.example", 1, 0, "ExemploController");

    view.setSource(QUrl(mainQmlApp));
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    QObject::connect(view.engine(), SIGNAL(quit()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
    view.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 400, 400));
    view.show();

    return application.exec();
}
```

Controller:

Header file:

```
...
class ExemploController : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ExemploController(QWidget *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE void getMatrix();

signals:
    void receiveMatrix(QList <QList <double> > matrix);

public slots:
};
```

Implementation:

```
...
QList <QList <double> > net;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    QList<double> colorMatrix;
    colorMatrix << 1 << 2 << 1 << 2 << 2 << 2;
    net << colorMatrix;
}
emit receiveMatrix(net);
...
```

And.. in QML:

```
...
ExemploController {
    id: exemplo
    onReceiveMatrix: { 
        console.log(matrix+" "+matrix.length); //this returns 'qml: QVariant(QList<QList<double> >) undefined'
    }
}
...
```

How I can get these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have `QVariantList` and `QVariantMap` for easier iterating values in QML. You can attempt to use `QVariantList` instead of `QList`.

[QVariantList and QVariantMap to JavaScript Array and Object](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object).